# What are benefits of using puma / systemd with socket activation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, systemd, puma

I'm using Ruby on Rails 6 with Puma server managed by systemd on Ubuntu 20.04.

[On the official Puma website](https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/master/docs/systemd.md), two setups types are given:

- simple
- with socket activation

There it says:

> systemd and puma also support socket activation, where systemd opens the listening socket(s) in advance and provides them to the puma master process on startup. **Among other advantages**, this keeps listening sockets open across puma restarts and achieves **graceful restarts**, including when upgraded puma, and is compatible with both clustered mode and application preload.

[emphasis mine]

I have two questions:

- What's a "graceful" restart?
- What are the "other advantages"?

Answer (score 0):

One other advantage would be the use of 'system ports', e.g. port 80 while running puma as a non-root user.